# SXA Search Scope filters using sxa: ItemsWithTheSameValueInField

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.7 and using a search scope which filter using sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|FieldName, However it is not returning data in my search results. 
Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: 1. We don't know what is the type of `Created`; 2. If `Created` is a `datetime` are you sure that you want to match items by this field ? (datetime example `20180626T130408Z`, notice time section)

Comment: Created is just an example. If I type SXA:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|AnyField doesn't return data

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.
i have a template which has a field named category and i'm trying to filter the serach results by this category field. However, i don't get any results using this filter option.

Comment: Guys, check this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/sxa-search-scope-tokens/12590#12590