# SXA search scope tokens

Tags: sxa

When using `sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|Fieldname` with droplink field it is not filtering in search scope for example when adding in search scope :

```
sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|category
```

where the category is a droplink in the template of the context item, is the syntax above correct or should be added in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks fine.

I will write a few validation steps to help you.

### Validate query

Check your logs to see how Search Queries look like.

For my token configured in a following way:

`sxa:ItemsWithTheSameValueInField|Test`

I've got the following query:

`12996 19:42:15 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (sitecore_sxa_web_index): +_latestversion:1 +(+(+_path:0dae33a26f53473e8abdb054d9bf3b75 +searchable:1) +test:de30ff2da089418bb4922855609a3537)`

Notice this part:
`+test:de30ff2da089418bb4922855609a3537`

My context item where I execute the query from:
[image]

If your field is not in a query then it means that your context item does not contain this field. If it does and it looks good then move to a next step.

### Check index content

Make sure that your field is stored in the **SXA** index.

You can find your index against which you fire search queries when you open chrome dev tools:

[image]

My field looks like this:

[image]

Values in the index must be "comparable" with those from search queries.

If for example, your `category` field is a computed field, it will not work (normalized raw field value from an item has to be comparable with values in the index).

Comment: In sitecore 9.0 with Solr 6.6.2, the mapping of droplink field is stringcollection in sitecore configuration while when the column is indexed it is indexed like string so the query was constructed like "fieldname_sm" while solr index field as "fieldname_s" so the query was returning no data